# How to run a jnlp file with Java?

Tags: java, exec, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a JNLP file, normally I will execute with console (Linux) and works perfect.

```
javaws launch.jnlp
```

But now I have to run from Java code, I tried this...

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"path/to/.jnlp"});
p.waitFor();
```

Not working, as it should run.

Comment: `javaws launch.jnlp ` is also what you have to exec (with path likely)

Comment: sorry but i not understand.

Comment: I think what he's saying is Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"javaws path/to/.jnlp"});

Comment: ahhh ok , now understand , but still not work ** Cannot run program "javaws /var/www/Projects/jnlp/jnlp1/launch.jnlp" ** , This is my code ** Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"javaws /var/www/Projects/jnlp/jnlp1/launch.jnlp"}); **

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws /var/www/Projects/jnlp/jnlp1/launch.jnlp");
exec.waitFor();
```

**In linux:**

1. give execute permissions to the file `.jnlp`.
2. Add `javaws` in the path of the function:

   ```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws Path/to/jnlp");
   ```

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also be sure to use a `String[] args` (array) of arguments over a `String arg` to account for things like paths with spaces in them.

Comment: I see no reason for execute permissions on the jnlp here

Answer (score 1):

It `the.jnlp` is in `user.home` it is as simple as:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
f = new File(f, "the.jnlp");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(f); // Launches the associated application to open the file.
```